# Can php's garbage collection delete the session of the initiating script

Tags: php, session

Suppose I have these settings in my php.ini file (which of course are not "normal" settings):

```
session.gc_maxlifetime = 60
session.gc_probability = 1
session.gc_divisor = 1
```

This means that in every session initialization, the garbage collection will run and cleanup all sessions older than a minute.

Let's suppose that there is only a single user connected to the server and runs a script that initializes the session. If he/she runs it again after 70 seconds (or anything more than 60  anyway), will his/her own session be deleted?

In other words, does the garbage collection happen before or after the script is executed?

Comment: It doesn't matter when it happens, if their session hasn't expired, it won't be garbage-collected. The session timeout is a completely different setting.

Answer (score 0):

The garbage collection should happen before running the script. This is the correct behavior. I mean, the session should be expired at any moment after `gc_maxlifetime`. PHP should do the garbage collection before running the script to make sure it's working correctly.

I was curious however, and tried it out, and my tests approved my presumption.

It was a simple test. With the given setup, I tested if a variable stored in session is there after X seconds, and it's not. So the garbage collection was done before running the script.

Note: You also have to set the session cookie lifetime to expire, if you use cookies.

Comment: The garbage collection does not run before the script - it is run when `session_start()` is called.  However, as you found, GC happens before the session is initialised, and therefore will delete the session before it can be loaded.  The end result is therefore as you describe, even though your explanation is not quite right, at a technical level.

Answer (score 0):

Builtin session GC is started during session initialization ([see gc_divisor](http://www.php.net/manual/en/sessionhandler.gc.php)), i.e. by `session_start()` function. When `session.autostart` is true the `session_start()` is executed before the first line of code.

Comment: This doesn't quite answer the question - it says that GC happens 'during' session initialisation without indicating whether this is before or after the script attempts to locate the requested session file.  This is a crucial detail in order to answer this question.

Comment: It is either BEFORE the first line of the code, or when/where `session_start()` is invoked.